# Python upgrade and requirements compatibility

Tags: python, requirements.txt, versionupgrade

I have a Python 3.6 project that I want to migrate to Python 3.8. I also have a
`requirements.txt` file generated with `pip freeze`, which is used by the Python 3.6 project. Is there a way to know if the packages listed in `requirements.txt`, with their own specific pinned version, support/are compatible with Python 3.8?

I could imagine some ways to do that, like check the packages classifiers or look at `tox.ini` and so on, but the requirements file has ~300 packages listed and doing that manually would be cumbersome at best.

Comment: I've got python 3.8 installed, if you post your requirements.txt here, I can check for you.

Comment: If you do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` under the new version of Python (in a venv), it'll tell you if it can't find that particular version of a package for it

Comment: You can create a new virtualenv with python 3.8 and install the dependencies

Comment: @JiříBaum straight to the point. if you want to make your comment an answer I'll check it green. Out of curiosity, do you know if is that stated in some official docs?

Comment: Sorry, that's just based on experience; would have to search for docs...

Comment: @JiříBaum no need to be sorry or search the docs for me, thanks btw. I just asked because I tried to install my requirements.txt on python 3.9 and yep got a problem (compiling lxml, which with python 3.6 and 3.8 worked perfectly...), but the output didn't say nothing specific about incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` under the new version of Python (in a venv), it'll tell you if it can't find that particular version of a package for it

If there are several missing, it'll be a bit annoying, because it'll only tell you one at a time, but hopefully there won't be too many

Not sure if there's an official documented procedure in the docs, but this should give you a quick idea, especially on the happy path where it just works